# Expected value of a function with multiple variables from a exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I have three random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ **iid** and each drawed from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. I need calculate:

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 })$.

I did the following:

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 }) = \int_{x_3=0}^\infty\int_{x_2=0}^\infty\int_{x1=0}^\infty \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3} \lambda^3 e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2+x_3)} $ (I used the definition of expected value of $g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 }$)

First, I don't know if I am going in the right way. If I am, then I have the problem that I am not able to solve that integral (I have been trying with solvers too (calculator, symbolab, wolframalpha)).

I would apprecciate for any suggestion or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- What is $E\left[\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}\right] + E\left[\frac{X_2}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}\right] + E\left[\frac{X_3}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}\right]$?
- The random variables $\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}$, $\frac{X_2}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}$, and $\frac{X_3}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Cute. (+1) $\space$

Comment: Oh! I see, tell me if I am wrong. I think the first point is equal to 1, and if the three random variables are of the same distribution they should have an expected value (say $e$), so all together results in an expected value of $e$ = 1/3 Isn't it?

Comment: @DiegoMachado Yep. Note that this is true as long as $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) (i.i.d. is a special case of exchangeable). They don't even need to be exponentially distributed.

Comment: I understand! Thanks a lot :DD